# v3 api returns blocked content even with videoEmbedable = True

Tags: youtube-api

I am using v3 api and videoEmbeddable="true" in my search request.

However, when I try to play the video(s) on my webpage, it says the content is blocked to be displayed on this site. Watch it on Youtube.

Is there a parameter that I can use which will not return non-embeddable videos?

**EDIT **

Video Response:

```
{u'items': [{u'snippet': {u'title': u'Jerez - Yamaha Preview'}, u'contentDetails': {u'definition': u'hd', u'contentRating': {u'ytRating': u'ytAllAudiences'}, u'caption': u'false', u'duration': u'PT1M21S', u'licensedContent': True, u'dimension': u'2d'}, u'status': {u'publicStatsViewable': True, u'privacyStatus': u'public', u'uploadStatus': u'processed', u'license': u'youtube', u'embeddable': True}, u'id': u'aaR72Xf_4wc'}]}
```

Query:

```
return yt_service_v3.videos().list(
  id='aaR72Xf_4wc',
  part="id,snippet,contentDetails,status",
  fields="items(id,snippet(title),contentDetails,status)",
).execute()
```

This video is not embeddable on my webpage and in the response there is nothing to suggest that this video is not embeddable.

I request both contentDetails and status. I am not requesting via mobile device

Please provide pointers.

Comment: Do you have an example by chance? Both the query and the returned video that is blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small subset of videos have domain-level whitelists or blacklists applied to them by their content owners. Those restrictions are not reflected in API responses.

This is what you're seeing with `aaR72Xf_4wc` and the relevant portion of the [blog post about playback restrictions](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html) is

> There are even more subtle restrictions that occasionally come into
>   play. Not all of these are currently queryable via the API. For
>   instance, some videos are only playable on a certain set of domains.

Comment: I request/hope google/YT can do something about it. External devs put in lot of effort for excellent user experience and this is un-desirable. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hi Jeff, can something be done for this issue? Because these videos are watchable on Youtube. What do I need to do to get rights/access to play these videos on my site? Any special request I need to file? Please provide assistance?

Comment: There is nothing you can do; it's up to the content owner of the video to determine where they can be embedded.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it wasn't there 2.5 years ago, but the current API does have indication for **regional block**, when requesting contentDetails. here's a response for such request for 2 videos, the first one is blocked and the second one is not. Note the `regionRestriction` key:

```
{u'etag': u'"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/ZqEbAZJ-JFnYX3v37ZRuhK8FFN8"',
 u'items': [{u'contentDetails': {u'caption': u'false',
    u'definition': u'sd',
    u'dimension': u'2d',
    u'duration': u'PT2M5S',
    u'licensedContent': False,
    u'regionRestriction': {u'blocked': [u'NU',
      u'BY',
      u'NP',
      u'NR',
      u'WS',
      u'TD',
      u'SY',
      u'NZ',
      u'NE',
      .
      .
      .
      u'TG']}},
   u'etag': u'"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/hM4srkgNUiZj2GtAhLDFoFrHnlk"',
   u'id': u'WGf4mSBoCzQ',
   u'kind': u'youtube#video'},
  {u'contentDetails': {u'caption': u'false',
    u'definition': u'sd',
    u'dimension': u'2d',
    u'duration': u'PT17M2S',
    u'licensedContent': False},
   u'etag': u'"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/JNjXh3lMwcaC9gtbzM-KmOQLh44"',
   u'id': u'Tw75Dt8fBBs',
   u'kind': u'youtube#video'}],
 u'kind': u'youtube#videoListResponse',
 u'pageInfo': {u'resultsPerPage': 2, u'totalResults': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also [filter by syndicatio](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated)n if you are accessing from a mobile device. Last but not the least there are [region specific blockages](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction).

Comment: I edited my post. contentDetails of the blocked video does not have regionRestriction in it and status.embeddable = true. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to also include the filter for `videoSyndicated`. I don't know for sure though; it's a little confusing to me.