# "Embeddable" youtube video can't be embedded

Tags: javascript, video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the v3 youtube API to get video data based on its id.

Here is my current search:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,status&id=QGGyYVsEGGo&key=<my_key>
```

The video id I included is the particular case I'm curious about. It returns a status property that has the following information:

```
status: {
  uploadStatus: "processed",
  privacyStatus: "public",
  license: "youtube",
  embeddable: true,
  publicStatsViewable: true
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) the `status.embeddable` property...

`" indicates whether the video can be embedded on another website."`

If you look at this JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tewj3xco/) I used their iframe player to display the same video as above and it says that the NFL has blocked it. I'm wondering if there is a different or more reliable property to check to know whether or not a video from youtube can be embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156532/3037988), there is no way to obtain this information through the API.

> A small subset of videos have domain-level whitelists or blacklists applied to them by their content owners. Those restrictions are not reflected in API responses.