# Why can't I embed some YouTube videos in my web page? (Video has the embeddable property set to true)

Tags: angular, youtube-api, embed, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to embed videos in my web page... I'm using @angular/youtube-player.

To get the videos I'm using YouTube API, my query params to it look something like this:

```
    "videoEmbeddable": "true",
    "videoCategoryId": "10",
    "maxResults": "15",
    "part": "snippet",
    "type": "video",
```

So I thought if I set the videoEmbeddable to true I should only get videos that can be embedded. In the list of videos I got I have this one, for example: ***aZ5fQyiZgns***

If I find that videoId in the YT API it says that it is embeddable

[image: Embeddable is true]

But once I try to visit this link https://www.youtube.com/embed/aZ5fQyiZgns it doesn't work and says "*Video not available*" which is the same thing I see in my webpage when I try to show it.

[image: YT video error. Not available]

I read YT might have been failing because I was accessing my app with IP, so I set a hostname in my hosts file but that didn't help.

Also tried using HTTPS but that didn't change anything either.

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156532/5126036. Might this be the reason I'm getting that error? Is there another way to filter videos that can actually be embedded?

I'm using Angular 13 for the frontend and my backend is on Django (3, 2, 9, 'final', 0)

Other video ids that are failing for me:

- 50dZQkrqxAk
- 0yW7w8F2TVA
- Mhj15W23IjA
- 9fawaFE0pPg
- mdndTRMvPu0
- y8OtzJtp-EM
- PukKW3gY4uo
- D2lSwosw9xY
- UelDrZ1aFeY
- 2TtgkKZNTa8
- rjCBV6o_DSE

**Update:** I uploaded my app to a server. The server can't embed the videos mentioned above. But the good news are that the query to the YT API doesn't return this videos. So it seems like the query to YT from my local is returning videos that can't be embedded. Still not sure what the problem is though.

*Note: I'm not a native English speaker, if there's something that can't be understood please let me know and I'll try to clarify.*

Comment: YouTube cannot access your HOSTS file.

Comment: @MikeMeinz Thank you for your answer. I tried uploading my code into a server with a domain name and same thing happened with those videos. (Check my update in the original question)

Comment: I tried playing some of your videos using the [following video player](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player) and it's working as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't link directly to https://www.youtube.com/embed/aZ5fQyiZgns as it will show video unavailable.

It has to be in an iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aZ5fQyiZgns" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

or you can link to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5fQyiZgns (works fine)

Comment: Hello @johnh10 I'm using @angular/youtube-player, and it creates an iframe, it looks something like this 

<iframe allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="YouTube video player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x253JA_0Uqs?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000&amp;widgetid=3" id="widget4" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Still doesn't work though (for some videos)

Comment: Your OP specifically said it was a link. Please edit and put your embed code exactly for people to help.